# Get variables from a Distance Matrix, Google Maps v3

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

The problem is that i have this code:

```
function calcDist() {
    var calcdirection = document.getElementById('street').value + "+" + document.getElementById('number').value + "+UK";
    for (var x = 0; x < dbdirection.length; x++) {
        var dirdest = dbdirection[x].replace(" ","+")+ "+UK";
        $.getJSON("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins="+calcdirection+"&destinations="+dirdest+"&mode=walking&language=es-ES&sensor=false", function(datos) {
            var distance = datos.rows[0].elements[0].distance.value;
        //  return distance;
          });
    //  alert(distance);
    }
}
```

And I can't get the distance value outside the `getJSON`. I was searching about this and I found that i can use `"&callback="` at the end of the url, but it doesn't work for me (probably because I'm not sure about how to use it).
How can I solve it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the result in an HTML element with `JQuery.data()` function:

```
$('#div_id').data('distance', distance)
```

And after that you can load the results:

```
var distance = $('#div_id').data('distance')
```

use the `async: false` option in `$.getJSON()` to avoid `undefined` errors